# Define a target that depends on a value/variable that need to be resolved

Tags: makefile

**Updated my question as it seemed to be not clear enough!**

I was listing when to use make over bash. One thing I like about `make` is its declarative way of describing necessary steps; we can write a rule by relying on other rules knowing how to provide necessary files (or other external states).

I'm wondering how I can get the same benefit for a **value** not a file, without changing outer world (like leaving a temporary file).

```
hello.txt: (here, tell that it needs to resolve person's name)
    # Here, person's name is available.
    echo Hello $(var_name) > $@
```

We can imperatively prepare a necessary value with `$(call prepare_name, ...)` at the beginning of a command in a rule, but that's not what I'm after here.

I posted my attempts as an answer when I opened this question. Hopefully that adds more info on what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: It's not overly clear what you're after.   How would it resolve the persons name?   Is the name available in a variable, in a file?  did you want it to prompt a person for their name?

Comment: @HardcoreHenry I'm not thinking a specific scenario to get a value (`var_name`) here, but with some complex calculation that I want to separate it from hello.txt rule. The value retrieval may depend on other targets. I'm exploring a pattern in general and doesn't have a real usecase at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a way using `eval` function. Below suppose `foo` is a value obtained by a complex calculation.

```
hello.txt: var_name
    echo Hello $($<) > $@

.PHONY: var_name
var_name:
    $(eval $@ = foo)
```

Or with `.INTERMEDIATE` target, this also works, but I feel it's more complicated.

```
var_name = var-name.txt

hello.txt: $(var_name)
    echo Hello $$(< $<) > $@

.PHONY: $(var_name)
.INTERMEDIATE: $(var_name)
$(var_name):
    rm -f $@        # In case the var file already exists
    echo bar > $@
```

Another way could be to use a target-specific variable. It's not listing a variable as a prerequisite, but I still don't need to think about how to get `var_name` when writing `echo Hello ...`.

```
define get_name
echo foo
endef

hello.txt: var_name = $(call get_name)
hello.txt:
    echo Hello $(var_name) > $@
```

Comment: May I ask what you are trying to achieve? The dependency on something which has no persistency (i.e. across more than one invocation of make) is usually solved by the programmatic part of a makefile.

Comment: Hi @Vroomfondel, I was listing when to use make over bash. One thing I like about make is the declarative way of describing necessary steps, but it works well when intermediate steps updates external states (typically by creating files) and not when updating internal states (variables). I'd like to see how I can treat a variable as a prerequisite and focus on getting a rule right by assuming another rule takes care of preparing a necessary value. But it may just complicates things and better doing it with an imperative way by `call`ing a variable to produce a value in `hello.txt` rule.

Answer (score 0):

It's not overly clear what you're after, however to clarify a few concepts:

A target must be dependent on other targets.   It cannot be dependent on a variable name.   It can be dependent on the value of a variable, if that variable resolves to a target name.

So you could do:

```
VAR=some_target
hello.txt: $(VAR)
    echo "hello $^" > $@   

some_target:
    touch $@
```

You CANNOT do:

```
VAR=some_target
hello.txt: VAR
```

and expect it to work (make would try to build `VAR` which likely doesn't exist and it would fail).

I'm assuming from the question that you want make to request the variable name of a person, and put that into hello.txt.   In that case you would likely want to store the name in a temporary file and use that for the output:

```
 .getname.txt:
     @read -p "enter name" name > $@

 hello.txt: .getname.txt
     @echo "hello $$(cat $$<)" > $@
```

This will update .getname.txt if it didn't previously exist (so it will not necessarily ask on every invokation of make...).   You could make .getname.txt be a .PHONY target, and it will run every time.

If you do want to run every time, then you can simply do:

```
 hello.txt:
     @read -p "enter name: " name && echo "hello $$name" > $@

 .PHONY: hello.txt
```

Which will invoke the hello.txt rule regardless of whether hello.txt already exists, and will always prompt the user for a name and rebuild hello.txt.

Comment: Thanks @HardcoreHenry, I was exploring how to make a target depend on a value/variable even though it's not natural to do it in `make`. I believe your temporary file solution is on the same line with one of my solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

As noted in other answers, make track dependencies between files, using timestamps. The regular solution for handling a value will be to store it in a file (or to generate it into a file). Assuming that there is significant work to do whenever the data is changing, you can follow one of the patterns below to implement dependency check on the file value.

The following makefile snapshot will trigger rebuild of complex-result, only when the content of var-value is modified. This is useful when the content of var-value is continuously regenerated, but does not change very frequently.

```
all: complex-result

last-value.txt: var-value.txt
        cmp -s $< $@ || cat <$^ > $@

complex-result: last-value.txt
        echo Buildig for "$$(cat var-value.txt)"
        touch $@
```

Or more realistic example: trigger a build if the value (content) of any file was modified, using md5 checksum,

```
all: complex-result

last-value.txt: $((wildcard *.data)
    md5sum $^ > $@ 

last-value.txt: var-value.txt
        cmp -s $< $@ || cat <$^ > $@

complex-result: last-value.txt
        echo Building for "$$(cat var-value.txt)"
        touch $@
```

Comment: Thanks @dash-o, I should have written in my question in the first place, but I was after a way where I don't leave `var-value.txt` or `last-value.txt` after make execution; hence describing it as **value**. But yes, if the scenario was, it requires significant work after the data change, keeping the files makes sense.